# Possible to read title of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'd like to make the title of my webpage the same title of the `iframe` I'm embedding in the webpage. Can I read the title of the `iframe` webpage through JavaScript?

***UPDATE***: The ports are the same, the domains only change by subdomain. Can that help?

***UPDATE 2***: I may be able to have users put in some JavaScript to their pages. If I can do that, is there a mechanism I can retrieve the title in the parent page?

Comment: If your page and the page within the iframe are part of the same domain, yes. If not, just forget about it.

Comment: POJS, or a framework like jQuery would be good too ?

Comment: The page is at www.mydomain.com and the page within the iframe is at username.users.mydomain.com, can that work?

Comment: As far as I know, cross domain access is not allowed due to security reasons.

Comment: @zaf - very helpful thanks... and of course not true. My attempts didn't work.

Comment: @at. Sorry for the previous comment mood but just try it out. Most probably it will work with sub domains unless its IE6.

Comment: Can't get it to work this way within a domain. What about if I can have users insert JavaScript in their page loaded by the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can not if child iframe has a different domain and port as the parent iframe, that is called Same Origin Policy see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) mdn document.

If the two iframe's has same origin(same domain and port), then you can access contents of child iframe via parent iframe using javascript.

Comment: won't be the same domain